# Serverless-next.js homepage (index.js) is returning a blank page

Tags: next.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify, serverless

I am wondering if anybody is facing or has faced this issue before. I am using `"serverless-next.js": "^1.14.0"` and when I deploy my website, every page loads except the homepage (index.js).

I get a complete blank page without any errors.

If I rename the index.js to another another name, then the path loads correctly.

I do not have any error logs to show since it actually returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `serverless-next.js@1.14.0` is not compatible with the latest `Next.JS (>9.5.4)`.

I had to downgrade my NextJS version back to `9.4.4` before issue resolved.
I have reported this to the Serverless-next.js community.